# HashTable namespace could not be found ASP

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a test.aspx.cs file and I use HashTable in the code. But, the compiler always complains it cannot find the namespace for it. I already added the System.Collections; namespace, but it still shows the same error! What is the problem??

Comment: Why would you not use a Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but you're most probably instantiating the hashtable like this:

```
HashTable table = new HashTable();
```

Change it to:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
```

Comment: @Deni : You were right! I can't believe I made such a silly mistake! Need some sleep i think ~~ thanks a lot!